# Print a column from Unix file

Tags: unix, awk

I have a unix file something like this

```
Name : abc
Name : def
Value : 123
Value_old : 456
```

I want to print abc,def,123,456 only.I am using `awk -F'' '{print $3}' file` but it is returning incorrect results.

Comment: Change it to `awk -F: '{ print $2 }'` then it should work.  It is more efficient to use `cut` though

Comment: I'm curious - what did you think `-F''` would do and why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
awk '{print $3}' file
```

did the work.

Answer (score 3):

You can use cut:

```
cut -d':' -f2
```

Answer (score 1):

```
awk -F'' '{print $3}'
```

won't work.

- `-F` is delimiter, here obviously, it should be `:`
- `$3` means column 3, in your input, there are only two columns

So it should be `awk -F':' '{print $2}'`

There are many ways to get your input, like `cut` in the other answer.

Also, grep:

```
grep -o '[^:]*$'
```

sed:

```
sed 's/[^:]*://'
```

Answer (score 0):

change delimiter:

```
awk -F": " '{print $2}' filename
```